# How do I create multiline text and page split in jspdf?

Tags: javascript, html, jspdf

I am trying to output the text content of a collection of text area inputs as a pdf file using jspdf. I can't work out how to put in line breaks or use the pagesplit:true option as it doesn't take it as an argument in doc.text. I see the a similar question was asked 25 days ago but I don't understand how to implement the answer and am not sure it would work for multiple text areas. I would greatly appreciate any advice.

```
<html>
<title>Multi-line/pagesplit</title>
<body>
<form action="#" method="post" id="myForm">
    <table id="myTable">
        <tr>
            <td>Please enter text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="myText" wrap="soft" placeholder="Your text..."></textarea></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<input type="button" value="Download as PDF" onclick="downloadPDF()"/></button>
<script>
function downloadPDF(){
    var text = document.getElementById("myText").value;
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.setFontSize(12);
    doc.text(20, 20, text);
    doc.save('Test.pdf');
    ;
}
</script>
<script src="jspdf.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: I found a really helpful answer here: [Word wrap in generated PDF (using jsPDF)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24272058/word-wrap-in-generated-pdf-using-jspdf) and managed to tweak it slightly for my needs. It seems that the necessary plugins were already in jspdf.min.js. Here's the code I've ended up using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Multi-line/pagesplit</title>
<body>
<form action="#" method="post" id="myForm">
    <table id="myTable">
        <tr>
            <td>Please enter text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="myText" wrap="soft" placeholder="Your text..."></textarea></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<input type="button" value="Download as PDF" onclick="downloadPDF()"/>.     </button>
<script>
function downloadPDF(){
    var text = document.getElementById("myText").value;
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    var splitText = doc.splitTextToSize(text, 250);
    var pageHeight = doc.internal.pageSize.height;
    doc.setFontSize(11);
    var y = 20;
    for (var i=0; i<splitText.length; i++){
        if (y > 275){
            y = 20;
            doc.addPage();
        }
        doc.text(20, y, splitText[i]);
        y = y + 5;
    }
    doc.save('Test.pdf');
    ;
}
</script>
<script src="jspdf.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```