# Autopaging jspdf when content increases

Tags: javascript, angular, jspdf

I'm trying to create a pdf that auto-pages when a content increases.
This is my sample code. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

HTML code

```
<div *ngFor="let data of data">
  <button click = "previewPdf(data)"> Preview </button>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
previewPdf(data) {
  var doc = new jsPDF();
  let bodyContent = doc.splitTextToSize(data.body, 250);
  let lineheight = 6;
  let offsety = 5;

  this.data.forEach(function(i) {
  doc.setFontSize(20);
  doc.text(10,10 + lineheight * 0 + offsety, bodyContent);
  doc.output("dataurlnewwindow");
});

}
```

JSON

```
data[{
  "body": "A very long letter content...";
}];
```

**Edit**:
I have tried this sample code below and its giving me 2 pages and the last page is blank

```
previewPdf(data) {
    var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');
    let pageHeight = doc.internal.pageSize.getHeight();
    let bodyContent = doc.splitTextToSize(data.body, 250);
    let lineheight = 6;
    let offsetY = 5;


    doc.text(10, 10, bodyContent);
    // Before adding new content
    let y = 840; // Height position of new content
    if (y >= pageHeight) {
      doc.addPage();
      y = 0 // Restart height position
    }


    // this.data.forEach(function(i) {
    //   doc.setFontSize(20);
    //   
    // });
    doc.output("dataurlnewwindow");
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working solution

```
  previewPdf(data) {
    var doc = new jsPDF();

    var bodyContent = doc.splitTextToSize(data.body, 250);
    var pageHeight = doc.internal.pageSize.getHeight();
    doc.setFontType("normal");
    doc.setFontSize("12");

    var y = 15;
    for (var i = 0; i < bodyContent.length; i++) {
      if (y+10 > pageHeight) {
        y = 15;
        doc.addPage();
      }
      doc.text(10, y, bodyContent[i]);
      y = y + 7;
    }    
     doc.output('dataurlnewwindow');

  }
```

Comment: above formula combined with the text wrap splitTextToSize(); based from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/43611535/8673882

Answer (score 1):

You can use [addHTML](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/releases/tag/v1.0.138) for that using *pagesplit* parameter

**Edit:**

There's another dirty hack where you can calculate the height of the page remaining before adding content

```
doc = new jsPdf();

pageHeight= pdf.internal.pageSize.height; //get total page height
```

Then when adding content check height condition like below

```
pdf.text(x, y, "value");

if (y>=pageHeight)
{
pdf.addPage();
}
```

Comment: `var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
var options = {
         pagesplit: true
    };

pdf.addHTML($(".pdf-wrapper"), options, function()
{
    pdf.save("test.pdf");
});`